# What is the meaning of BTC Transaction?

Tags: transactions

I'm studying BTC Transaction

What is the BTC transaction below mean?

Input(1)

- bc1asd~ : 0.00741579 BTC

Output(2)

- 1ASDAC~ : 0.00678954 BTC
- Binance(bc1q~~~5d24) : 0.0003 BTC

---

What is 0.0003 BTC?

A transfer fee? or change?

And, Is it a transaction from one Binance wallet to another?

please let me know
please...

Answer (score 1):

There are no transfer fees in Bitcoin, Only transaction fees. The transaction fees are not shown as outputs but are sum of outputs minus sum of inputs.

It is often impossible to distinguish change from payment. This is deliberate.

It is usually impossible to know what person or organisation controls the keys for an address, if they care about their privacy.

Answer (score 0):

most this is self explanatory - input1 is wallet the coins cam from and the 2 outputs are the walletrs the coins are going to. - No they dont have be binance wallets as far as I know. 0.0003 BTC is the value of ur cash in bitcoins - everytime there is movemet of coins on the chain it is known as a transaction. The fees are what the miners make for doing the calculations and making sure everything goes where we have asked it to go